# Python Regular Expression - Replace String Based Repeated Patterns

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I want to transform the string `L^2 M T^-1` to `L^2.M.T^-1`. The dot replaces the space (\s) only if it is between two word characters. For example, if the string is 'lbf / s' no replacement will be applied.

```
str1= 'L^2 M T^-1'

pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+\s\w+)+')
def pattern_match2(m):
    me = m.group(0).replace(' ', '.')
    return me

pattern.sub(pattern_match2, str1) # this produces L2.MT-1
```

How can i replace the string with dot (.) by repeated patterns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` directly instead of finding a match and then using `str.replace`. Also, I'd use `\b` instead of `\w` since `\w` matches any `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, while `\b` encapsulates it in a smarter way (in essence it is equivalent to `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
)

```
import re

print(re.sub(r'\b(\s)\b', '.', 'L^2 M T^-1'))
# L^2.M.T^-1

print(re.sub(r'\b(\s)\b', '.', 'lbf / s'))
# lbf / s
```

Comment: i didnt use re.sub directly as the actual pattern_match2 include few other replacements, not only (.). Thanks..